# Attempting to build and run Shrinkr using Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2, sql-server-2008

Recently at work, I was tasked with implementing a URL shortener for my department to use internally.  We're largely a ASP.NET MVC shop (whenever possible), so naturally I gravitated towards the open source http://shrinkr.codeplex.com/.  However, Entity Framework is foreign to me and I have no idea how to actually get this up and running.  I've created a SQL08R2 database for it, and passed it (what should be) a valid connection string:

```
    <add name="Shrinkr" connectionString="Data Source=sql08r2.myFQDN;Initial Catalog=Shrinkr;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Building and running it in Debug mode yields the following error: 
[image: alt]

Of course, my database is empty and has no table structure.  I just can't figure out how the heck to get the database populated with the correct initial schema.  I've heard that EF can autogenerate the database, but I'm not sure if that applies in this case.  If there is a SQL file in the Shrinkr release to get the DB up and running, I sure as heck can't find it.  I've been banging my head against my desk for a few days now on this and I can't figure out what I'm missing!

Comment: EF *can* generate DBs, but that doesn't mean that you *should* generate the DB for some random app just because it uses EF. You need to find app-specific instructions for Shrinkr.

Comment: Craig: Agreed, but as far as I can tell, there are none. :-\  To be fair, there is a fair amount of complexity in the solution structure, so I could very well be missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just downloaded the source, and there is a create.sql script in the Database folder.  Sounds like that is what you're looking for.

Comment: Redownloaded the source, and yes there is :-)  I must have nuked it somehow when I originally extracted it.